# How to use file from Databricks FileStore

Tags: scala, apache-spark, databricks

Trying to use a `.dat` file for ip lookup. File is on Databricks file store from Scala code:

```
  def getCountryCode(ip: String) {
     val filePath = "FileStore/maxmind/GeoIPCountry.dat"
     val ipLookups = new IpLookups(geoFile = Option(new File(filePath)),
  ispFile = None, orgFile = None, domainFile = None, memCache = false, lruCache = 0)

     val location = ipLookups.performLookups(ip)._1.head
     println(location.countryCode)
  }
```

I am getting an exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: FileStore/maxmind/GeoIPCountry.dat (No such file or directory)
```

Method works on local environment with relative/absolute paths

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use fully qualified path to the file on the FUSE mounted file system:

```
val filePath = "/dbfs/FileStore/maxmind/GeoIPCountry.dat"
```

Reference: [Using Local File I/O APIs](https://docs.databricks.com/user-guide/dbfs-databricks-file-system.html#using-local-file-i-o-apis).